# Detecting Mouse clicks in windows using python

Tags: python, windows, mouse

How can I detect mouse clicks regardless of the window the mouse is in?

Perferabliy in python, but if someone can explain it in any langauge I might be able to figure it out.

I found this on microsoft's site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645533(VS.85).aspx

But I don't see how I can detect or pick up the notifications listed.

Tried using pygame's pygame.mouse.get_pos() function as follows:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
while True:
    print pygame.mouse.get_pos()
```

This just returns 0,0.
I'm not familiar with pygame, is something missing?

In anycase I'd prefer a method without the need to install a 3rd party module.
(other than pywin32 http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/ )

Comment: Which UI toolkit/library are you using?

Comment: I think this should be possible using win32ui and ctypes.  I found that I can get the mouse position with windll.user32.GetCursorPos(pointer(pt_struct)) (For details: http://monkut.webfactional.com/blog/archive/2008/10/2/python-win-mouse-position )

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The only way to detect mouse events outside your program is to install a Windows hook using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx). The [pyHook](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/developer.shtml) module encapsulates the nitty-gritty details. Here's a sample that will print the location of every mouse click:

```
import pyHook
import pythoncom

def onclick(event):
    print event.Position
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDown(onclick)
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
hm.UnhookMouse()
```

You can check the **example.py** script that is installed with the module for more info about the **event** parameter.

pyHook might be tricky to use in a pure Python script, because it requires an active message pump. From the [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20100501173949/http://mindtrove.info/articles/monitoring-global-input-with-pyhook/):

> Any application that wishes to receive
>   notifications of global input events
>   must have a Windows message pump. The
>   easiest way to get one of these is to
>   use the PumpMessages method in the
>   Win32 Extensions package for Python.
>   [...] When run, this program just sits
>   idle and waits for Windows events. If
>   you are using a GUI toolkit (e.g. 
>   wxPython), this loop is unnecessary
>   since the toolkit provides its own.

Comment: Note that PyHook has moved quite around meanwhile to https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyhook/

Comment: If you want to exit import the
`ctypes` 
library and then execute anywhere in the current thread:
`ctypes.windll.user32.PostQuitMessage(0) `
This will end `pythoncom.PumpMessages()`

Comment: Recently, like for Python 3.8+, this fork of pyHook may be helpful: https://pypi.org/project/pyWinhook/ It is also nice that it is on PyPI, so you don't have to deal directly with .whl files. The normal `pip install pyWinhook` should do the trick.

Answer (score 23):

I use win32api. It works when clicking on any windows.

```
# Code to check if left or right mouse buttons were pressed
import win32api
import time

state_left = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)  # Left button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128
state_right = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)  # Right button down = 0 or 1. Button up = -127 or -128

while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    b = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)

    if a != state_left:  # Button state changed
        state_left = a
        print(a)
        if a < 0:
            print('Left Button Pressed')
        else:
            print('Left Button Released')

    if b != state_right:  # Button state changed
        state_right = b
        print(b)
        if b < 0:
            print('Right Button Pressed')
        else:
            print('Right Button Released')
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

Answer (score 8):

It's been a hot minute since this question was asked, but I thought I'd share my solution: I just used the built-in module `ctypes`. (I'm using Python 3.3 btw)

```
import ctypes
import time

def DetectClick(button, watchtime = 5):
    '''Waits watchtime seconds. Returns True on click, False otherwise'''
    if button in (1, '1', 'l', 'L', 'left', 'Left', 'LEFT'):
        bnum = 0x01
    elif button in (2, '2', 'r', 'R', 'right', 'Right', 'RIGHT'):
        bnum = 0x02

    start = time.time()
    while 1:
        if ctypes.windll.user32.GetKeyState(bnum) not in [0, 1]:
            # ^ this returns either 0 or 1 when button is not being held down
            return True
        elif time.time() - start >= watchtime:
            break
        time.sleep(0.001)
    return False
```

Comment: Usage of built-in libraries wins this one (plus use of "hot minute")

Answer (score 5):

Windows MFC, including GUI programming, is accessible with python using the [Python for Windows extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) by Mark Hammond. [An O'Reilly Book Excerpt](http://www.onlamp.com/lpt/a/217) from Hammond's and Robinson's [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9781565926219/) shows how to hook mouse messages, .e.g:

```
self.HookMessage(self.OnMouseMove,win32con.WM_MOUSEMOVE)
```

Raw MFC is not easy or obvious, but searching the web for python examples may yield some usable examples.

Answer (score 2):

The windows way of doing it is to handle the `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` message.

For this to be sent, your window class needs to be created with the `CS_DBLCLKS` class style.

I'm afraid I don't know how to apply this in Python, but hopefully it might give you some hints.