# detecting idle time using python

Tags: python, winapi

How do I detect if the system is idle on Windows using Python (i.e. no keyboard or mouse activity).
This has already been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217157/how-can-i-determine-the-display-idle-time-from-python-in-windows-linux-and-maco), but there doesn't seem to be a `GetLastInputInfo` in the `pywin32` module.

Comment: Since it was asked before, why are you asking again?  What do you think has changed that will yield a different answer?

Comment: Maybe there's someone around now who can answer it, but the old question is buried in age and obscurity. How can you "bump" someone else's old question?

Comment: when it was previously asked, the answer was about detecting mouse clicks, which was nowhere near an answer to that question!

Answer (score 45):

```
from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref

class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0
```

Call `get_idle_duration()` to get idle time in seconds.

Comment: Another library could set `argtypes`, `restype`, or `errcheck` on `windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo` in an incompatible way, so you should use your own `WinDLL` instance, e.g. `user32 = WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)`.

Comment: @ErykSun , Sometimes this returns negative numbers, even with the user32 = ... code

Answer (score 17):

```
import win32api
def getIdleTime():
    return (win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) / 1000.0
```

Comment: This yields a number less than 1 which does not seem to increase over time. It resets to zero when input is detected, but then it just becomes 0.015 or 0.016 and stays there.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like `GetLastInputInfo` is now available in pywin32:

```
win32api.GetLastInputInfo()
```

does the trick and returns the timer tick from the last user input action.

Here with an example program

```
import time
import win32api
for i in range(10):
   print(win32api.GetLastInputInfo())
   time.sleep(1)
```

If one presses a key/moves the mouse while the script sleeps, the printed number changes.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can access `GetLastInputInfo` via the `cytpes` library:

```
import ctypes
GetLastInputInfo = ctypes.windll.User32.GetLastInputInfo  # callable function pointer
```

This might not be what you want though, as it does not provide idle information across the whole system, but only about the session that called the function.  [See MSDN docs.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(VS.85).aspx)

Alternatively, you could [check if the system is locked](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/see_if_my_workstation_is_locked.html), or if the screen-saver has been started.

Answer (score 2):

@FogleBird's answer is pretty cool and working, but in a hurry i wasn't sure how it works, so a little test example here. A thread is starting, looking for last idle time every 10 seconds. If any movement is made within this time window, it will be printed out.

```
from ctypes import Structure, windll, c_uint, sizeof, byref
import threading

//Print out every n seconds the idle time, when moving mouse, this should be < 10
def printit():
  threading.Timer(10.0, printit).start()
  print get_idle_duration()



class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0

printit()
```

Comment: note that as of some recent update (on my end) (windows 10), the time millis returns is not correct, replacing it with `(win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) / 1000.0` worked

Answer (score 2):

There's basically two types of answers so far.  One using `pywin32` (via `win32api` and one using `ctypes`.  The only thing I could think of distinguishing them would be time of execution, so here are the results of a timeit test:

```py
# idlefuncs.py

import ctypes
from ctypes import Structure, c_uint, sizeof, byref

import win32api

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL("user32", use_last_error=True)
kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL("kernel32", use_last_error=True)

class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]


def get_idle_duration():
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0


def getIdleTime():
    return (win32api.GetTickCount() - win32api.GetLastInputInfo()) / 1000.0
```

In ipython:

```
In[1]: from idlefuncs import *

In[2]: %timeit get_idle_duration()
1.21 µs ± 12 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
In[4]: %timeit getIdleTime()
465 ns ± 7.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Contrary to my expectations, the ctypes version takes 2.6 times as long!