# How can I get how long my computer's been idle (idle time) using python?

Tags: python, time

The computer obviously stores it sense it knows when to put the screen saver on. Is there a python program that can get the computer's idle time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detecting idle time using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911856/detecting-idle-time-using-python)

Comment: Please read tag explanations before using them.  `python-idle` is for the Python stdlib IDLE IDE and nothing to do with inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

This questions has already been answered several times it appears. A quick google search for this topic should give you other stack overflow Q's & A's for this question, but here is one of the previously answered links:

[detecting idle time using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911856/detecting-idle-time-using-python)

Comment: I did not have enough reputation to initiate a comment. I can only comment on other comments until I get 50 stack overflow reputation.