# How to detect idle time of mouse/keyboard only, not for other input devices?

Tags: python, windows, winapi

`GetLastInputInfo()`, eg [detecting idle time using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911856/detecting-idle-time-using-python), is sensitive to mouse and keyboard input, but it's also disturbed by game controller input, which I want to ignore.

Is there an easy way to do this?

One way is to use Raw Input, eg [Having trouble using winapi to read input from a device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71994439/having-trouble-using-winapi-to-read-input-from-a-device), which needs to be wrapped by synchronized write and read threads that record the events and can be queried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the pynput module to get user input using a keyboard and mouse listener. I have created a short example which disregards controller input. (at least on my pc)

```
from time import time
from pynput.keyboard import Listener as KeyListener
from pynput.mouse import Listener as MouseListener

idle_time = time()
txt = "You've been idle for {} seconds."


def tell_time():
    global idle_time
    print(txt.format(time() - idle_time))
    idle_time = time()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    KeyListener(on_press=lambda key: tell_time()).start()
    with MouseListener(
            on_move=lambda x, y: tell_time(),
            on_click=lambda x, y, btn, b: tell_time(),
            on_scroll=lambda a, b, c, d: tell_time()
    ) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

Comment: Cool. I assume you need to sync the threads with a lock (mutex).

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is install [system-wide hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) of type `WH_MOUSE_LL` and `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` that store the last mouse or keyboard input activity time in a way that can be read back by the code that loaded the DLL. There are many ways to communicate this data from the DLL back to the loader, including, but not limited to:

- The DLL itself exporting the timestamp in a function like GetLastActivityTime()
- Named shared memory
- Named pipes
- Mailslots
- A normal disk file
- A registry value
- TCP Communication

... so I won't give a detailed code example.

Note that hooks of type `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` are *very likely* to be detected as malware by antivirus software if your code is not digitally signed, since unknown code that uses this functionality is very likely to be a [keylogger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke_logging).

Comment: Ignoring the fact that low-level hooks are a horrible idea for observing input, how does a low-level mouse input hook distinguish between mouse and game controller input?

Comment: How is it any better/easier than using raw input?