# Python get idle duration on Linux

Tags: python

I'm making a script that gets the idle duration based on the last mouse or keyboard input time.
The following piece of code worked on Windows but I need one which would run on Linux.

```
class LASTINPUTINFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('cbSize', c_uint),
        ('dwTime', c_uint),
    ]

def get_idle_duration():
    # get idle time
    lastInputInfo = LASTINPUTINFO()
    lastInputInfo.cbSize = sizeof(lastInputInfo)
    windll.user32.GetLastInputInfo(byref(lastInputInfo))
    millis = windll.kernel32.GetTickCount() - lastInputInfo.dwTime
    return millis / 1000.0

print(get_idle_duration())
```

Can someone help me run this on both Windows and Linux?

Comment: _i canot make it run on linux_ Can you be more specific?

Comment: this function dont work in linux . only in windows os system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine the display idle time from Python in Windows, Linux, and MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217157/how-can-i-determine-the-display-idle-time-from-python-in-windows-linux-and-mac)

Answer (score 2):

You can refer [idle.py](https://dev.gajim.org/gajim/gajim/blob/89c7eb6e6ab3f61a188c6cee063a000526df522c/gajim/common/idle.py) by [Gajim](https://gajim.org/)

Just call the `getIdleSec()` to get the idle time in seconds.

If you execute `idle.py`, it will wait for 2.1 seconds and then print the idle time. Later it frees the held data after which if you call the function, it will return zero.

The problem with the code given in the question is that it uses `windll` which is specific to Windows.

If you want to see the script in action in a more detailed manner, you can change `main` as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import time
    for i in range(0,10):
        print(getIdleSec())
    close()
```

This works on Ubuntu and should work on all Debian based operating systems.