# Get Mouse Double Click with pyHook

Tags: c#, c++, python, winapi

I'm trying to get Mouse Double Clicks with pyHook, but instead I'm getting two pair entries of single clicks e.g. WM_LBUTTONDOWN (0x201)  and WM_LBUTTONUP (0x202) .  I'm expecting WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK (0x203).  What am I misssing here?

```
import pythoncom, pyHook

def OnMouseEvent(event):           
    print event.Message, event.Position
    return True

hm = pyHook.HookManager()
hm.MouseAll = OnMouseEvent
hm.HookMouse()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I've found this hint: In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python) MrZebra says: "For this (0x203) to be sent, your window class needs to be created with the CS_DBLCLKS class style"

**Edit**: [This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645606) indicates that doubleclicking will generate these 4 msgs:
WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK, and WM_LBUTTONUP, but I actually get the first two twice.

I'm using Python 2.7 and pyHook 1.5.1 on Win7x64

**ReEdit**: I'll consider as answers C++/C# Keyboard/Mouse hooks alternatives.  On the other hand, I'm not sure if it is a common practice to build functions to determine the double click event evaluating the time between two clicks.

Comment: Try adding a `hm.SubscribeMouseAllButtonsDbl(OnMouseEvent)` after the `hm = pyHook.HookManager()` statement.

Comment: I made the changes but the doubleclicks won't show.  I appreaciate a lot the advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting two `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` and `WM_LBUTTONUP` and no `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK` is because of what MrZebra says: the target window class' style does not include the `CS_DBLCLKS` style. Unless you can modify the source code for the target window class, it will never receive `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, because Windows will always break the double clicks into two separate clicks.

The only way to resolve this, is to measure the time between clicks. If the clicks come fast enough, then act as if you have received `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646258%28VS.85%29.aspx) for reading the double click time on Windows. Don't just assume that double clicks are 50 ms, or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Sigvardsson