# Python Automated Click Script

Tags: python, python-2.7, click

I am working on a program to make python auto click and type something in. I know this has been done before and asked before but no one has asked about recording mouse clicks to be "Played back" later on. I have the basic code set up from tutorials all over the place. I am wondering if I can get a hand with this. Here is what I have to this point:

```
import win32api, win32con
import time
def click(x,y):

    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)

print "Clicking 300, 300"
click(300,300)

time.sleep(3)

print "Clicking 800, 800"
click(800, 800)
```

How do I make this so the user can input and save a pre-generated script for clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't have any experience with the Win32 API, however, it should work along those lines:

1. The Module you are using needs to let you define a callback method for when a click happens
2. You somewhere set a boolean that tells you that you are currently recorded.
3. Your callback method stores tuples in a list:

   - The tuples store the timestamp (time.time) and the coordinates.
   - You can even store more information, like right-click or whatever.
4. When you are done recording you should have every informationen necessary to start replaying :)

(You may also consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python))
Hope it helps!

Comment: Looking into all of this I have most of it done already. I might save the "Recording" to an external file of some kind and have it read into the program as its needed. Might have some more questions Also I am open to other API's its just this was the first I found. LOL

Comment: Parsing files with Python is very easy and fun to do :)

Comment: For the time being this answers it. - Thank you!