# How to detect a right click (events) outside of Tkinter window in python 2.7 on windows?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Information I have come across related to this question has been for macs. Just trying to detect mouse clicks in order to trigger other processes.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can see a few stuff about that here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165495/detecting-mouse-clicks-in-windows-using-python

Comment: Thank you for your link. I now see I need pyhook. Something I was hoping to avoid since ill be lucky enough to get pip on my work computer, and pyhook cannot be installed with pip. Thank you again good sir.

Comment: mouse events will only work in tkinter when tkinter has the focus. If you need events that are outside the bounds of the tkinter program then you're going to need to use something platform specific.