# How can i make something when mouse click hold down with Python

Tags: python, mouseevent, mouselistener, onmouseclick

I want to make simply count the numbers automatically when mouse left click holding.
I can make it on keyboard but cant on mouse.

```
import keyboard

a = 0
while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
            a += 1;
            print(a)
    except:
        break
```

[code view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8ual.png)

When I press and hold it, it writes numbers on the screen by increasing it.
Just i want "mouse click then holding" version of this code.

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
def on_move(x, y):
    print("mouse moved")
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
    print("mouse clicked")
def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    print("mouse scrolled")
with Listener(on_move=on_move, on_click=on_click, on_scroll=on_scroll) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

The above codes running perfect but just i need mouse click holding event.
Or is there something like un_click event?

Comment: You need to create a window to receive the mouse click. Choose a GUI toolkit, follow a tutorial, and come back if you have a more concise question.

Comment: Sir, I couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596592/1084416