# overlay on other windows/desktop with python

Tags: python, graphics, overlay

My goal is to have a python program, that can project an overlay of boxes, rectangles, etc.
basically I want to be able to paint on my screen on top of whatever is currently active. The overlay-program should not intrude on the normal usage of what is "below" the overlay

Comment: I think you are looking for partially [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69151030/making-parts-of-canvas-transparent-while-still-detecting-and-blocking-mouse-clic/69154451#69154451) (Making parts of canvas transparent while still detecting and blocking mouse clicks in transparent areas in tkinter?) but with modifications, but you will need to ask a specific question and provide your attempts (a [mre])